# Кotlin и Android - видимость функции из другого файла, а не MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

некоторые функции хочу поместить в отдельный файл MyFunc.kt, а не в MainActivity.kt. Как сделать так, чтобы функции из MyFunc.kt можно было выбирать в конструкторе кнопок Design и вешать на свойство OnClick?

Comment: Импортировать..

Comment: [Добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1312835/edit) подробностей в ваш вопрос, объясните, что такое "конструктор кнопок Design", как это выглядит? Приведите пример кода, который вы пытались написать, и что конкретно у вас не получилось сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пусть файл `MyFunc.kt` с функцией `hello()` лежит в пакете `com.example.utils`:

```kotlin
package com.example.utils

fun hello() {
    println("Привет")
}
```

Чтобы использовать эту функцию в `MainActivity.kt`, сделаем импорт этой функции:

```kotlin
package com.example

import com.example.utils.hello

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        val button = findViewById(...)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            hello()
        }
    }

}
```

В одном файле может находится сразу несколько функций, каждую нужно импортировать отдельно. Если имя пакета совпадает с текущим, то функцию можно не импортировать.

Comment: Если package один и тот же, то можно и без импорта.

Comment: Да, добавил в ответ.

Comment: по условиям задачи - функции из MyFunc.kt нужно выбирать в конструкторе кнопок Design и вешать на свойство OnClick. А при таком импорте они не появляются в условиях выбора

Comment: и пока ещё вопрос если в функции hello() вывести Toast - ругается программа на this  в `Toast.makeText(this,"Нажата кнопка",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Comment: Я привел пример простейшей функции, потому что в вопросе не было сказано, какую функцию вы хотите вынести в другой файл. Если для вашей функции нужны какие-то дополнительные параметры, передайте их в аргументах функции.

Comment: Тосту нужен контекст, передайте контекст в аргументах: `hello(context: Context)`, либо сделайте hello [экстеншен-функцией](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/extensions.html): `Context.hello()`.

Comment: @Vadik спасибо за много полезной информации, поэтому пока тему закрою как решенную, хоть нужный ответ не получил - Как сделать так, чтобы функции из MyFunc.kt можно было выбирать в конструкторе кнопок Design и вешать на свойство OnClick? а не писать в коде (речь об Android Studio).